Github Actions : Provisioning profile "foo" doesn't include the currently selected device "Mac-1719908638417.local"
I've configured an CI/CD environment using Github Actions to build and deploy Apps automatically.
But since Github has updated the runner, I get the error Provisioning profile "foo" doesn't include the currently selected device "Mac-1719908638417.local" (identifier FOOO-BAAAAAAAAR).
After looking for a solution on web, I found nothing that works.
The only way I have today is to add the identifier used by runner in the Provisioning Profile but this task is tedious because each times new UUID is used by the runner.
So, there is a way to avoid this behavior ?
Maybe to use a fixed UUID, or use an identified selected device for the build, or another thing...

Were you using the macos-latest runner, or another version? It seems that it can be related to the xcodebuild setup (References: 1 + 2) so if this happened on the macos-latest runner, using an older version might still work as expected.

@GuiFalourd Yes I use macos-latest (macos-14) runner and I can't use lower version because my will be rejected by AppStore otherwise. (I'm not remember the error/warning).

After a few checks, I observed they updated the Xcode version on MacOs-14 runners yesterday. This might be related.

I do not think @GuiFalourd because I have this bad behavior since april. I presume since runner teams has updated Xcode to remove minimum app requirement issues from App Store.

What provisioning configuration are you using?

@Grzegorz Krukowski I'm not understand your question.
I use the provisioning provided by Developer console of Apple (AppStoreConnect).
I have a provisioning profile fro AppStore and provisioning for AdHoc. Generating app for AppStore by command line (Github Action) require AdHoc provisioning (I doesn't know why)
